# Get Salmon mapping/alignment summary

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-alignment, salmon

With HISAT2, after the alignment of fastq files you get an alignment summary like this:

```
20000 reads; of these:
  20000 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    1247 (6.24%) aligned 0 times
    18739 (93.69%) aligned exactly 1 time
    14 (0.07%) aligned >1 times
93.77% overall alignment rate
```

Is it possible to get this information with Salmon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `salmon` output log contains a line with `[info] Mapping rate` which allows to calculate how many reads went mapped or unmapped. Is that sufficient? It should be in the `logs` folder of the directory `salmon` creates per sample.